# QSerialPort not working correctly on Windows with specific device

Tags: c++, windows, qt, serial-port

**Edit**: I found the problem! To anyone with similar problems, here is what I did:

The device used Hardware Flowcontrol, which apperently is no problem with Linux but on Windows, this parameter has to be set explizitly!

### The Problem

We want to read out devices which trace the outline of a spectacle frame.
They use the RS232 Port. We've implemented the communication with the QSerialPort class from QT 5.7. Our Test-Setup currently features two tracers from diffenrent vendors and a Windows 7 PC. The communication with tracer 1 is working correctly; tracer 2 does not send any data to the Windows PC.

### Testing

For testing I've written a very simple programm wich just prints out all bytes as ASCII characters received via the serial-port. It also allows you to enter some text to send answers back to the device.
Testing the exact same sourcecode on Linux is working perfectly with both devices.
[Testsoftware on Linux (Device Requesting initialization)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAhS1.png)
. On Windows (using same cables and adapters) the log remains blank.
Connecting the Windows PC with a Nullmodem-Cable to the Linux PC or to the other device, the communication is working as expected.

Testing the communication with PuTTy on Windows, both devices are working.

### The Code

The code in the testapplication looks like this:

After setting up the parameters for the port and opening it:

```
QObject::connect(&m_serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(bytesReady()));
```

The slot:

```
void Device::bytesReady(){
while(m_serialPort.bytesAvailable()){
    emit read(m_serialPort.read(1).at(0));
}
```

}

After that, the "Konsole"-Class converts the Bytes received to readable ASCII characters and displays them in a QTextEdit

### Conclusion/Question

We are suspecting there is a bug in Qt or Windows, but we haven't any idea how to further investigate the problem. The testing on Linux shows that the device itself works fine, and our test program as well. Are there any setting in Windows or any spezial thing I've to do to setting up the serialPort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. See the top of the question for the solution.